# Как влияет амперсанд & на адрес переменной?

Tags: c, objective-c, указатели

Есть программа

```
#include    <stdio.h>
int main(int    argc,   const   char    *   argv[])
{
int i   =   17;
int *H = &i; //Здесь работает указатель.
printf("i   stores  its value   at  %p\n",  &i);
printf("H with &    stores  its value   at  %p\n",  &H);
 printf("H  stores  its value   at  %p\n",  H);
return  0;
}
```

Вывод примерно такой:

```
    i   stores  its value   at  0x7fff5fbff8bc
    H   with & stores   its value   at  0x7fff5fbff8a0
    H   stores  its value   at  0x7fff5fbff8bc
```

Легко увидеть, что `H` Без амперсанда хранится в памяти по тому же адресу, что и `i.` Но почему-то `&H` имеет другой адрес. 
Почему оно работает именно так?

Comment: Эээ... `&H` — это не адрес переменной `i`, это адрес переменной `H`. Вот в `H` **содержится** адрес переменной `i`.

Comment: Если вы знаете английский, вам поможет это: http://ericlippert.com/2014/05/12/what-are-the-fundamental-rules-of-pointers/

Comment: "_Легко увидеть, что H Без амперсанда хранится в памяти по тому же адресу, что и i._" - это где вы это "легко увидели" ? H хранится отдельно, что и выводит ваш второй print, а содержит в себе адрес i

Comment: господа а можно по подробнее, и развернуто?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin: Вы просите, чтобы мы объяснили вам, как работают указатели. Это требует длинного текста, который наверняка есть в любой книге.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При применении амперсанда к переменным мы получаем адрес памяти, где переменная расположена. Его мы можем присвоить в значение переменной, которая является указателем. У переменной которая является указателем тоже существует свой адрес, никак не связанный с тем, что хранится в этой переменной.

В вашем примере

```
printf("%p\n",  &i); // выводим адрес памяти, где расположена переменная i
printf("%p\n",  &H); // выводим адрес памяти, где расположена переменная H
printf("%p\n",  H);  // выводим значение переменной H, т. е. значение, которое расположено в памяти по адресу &H
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int i = 17;
```

Объявляется переменная для хранения целого числа типа `int`. Её адрес в Вашем случае `&i == 0x...f8bc`.

```
int *H = &i;
```

Объявляется переменная для хранения ***адреса*** другой переменной. В данном случае мы будем хранить адрес переменной `i`. Т.е. в `H` будет лежать значение `0x...ff8bc`. Но у `H` есть и свой адрес - `&H == 0x...f8a0`.

Для доступа к `i` через `H` используется *косвенная адресация*. Примерно она выглядит так:

*измени значение ячейки памяти, адрес которой находится в ячейке памяти с адресом `0x...`*

Comment: плюсанул, спасибо

Comment: Я бы добавил, что под `int i;` и `int* H;` на стеке (непосредственно сами указатели  ведь тоже создаются на стеке) выделяется по 4 байта (хотя на самом деле размер зависит от разрядности системы), т.е. каждая из этих переменных имеет свою область памяти (выделенную именно под неё), и эти области не пересекаются.